# Pandas: aggregate sum showing list

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am having issues getting `pandas` to aggregate and sum.

Sample from file:

```
18820   Multiple choice / by Zambra, Alejandro, ZAMBRA  B   F   15.00   15.00
18821   Green girl / by Zambreno, Kate, ZAMBREN B   F   15.00   15.00
18822   Milena, or, The most beautiful femur in the wo...   ZEPEDA  B   F   19.00   19.00
18823   Death notice : by Zhou, Haohui, ZHOU    B   F   27.00   27.00
18824   Billy Pintos war / by Zimmer, Michael,  ZIMMER  B   F   26.00   26.00
```

My code:

```
print_itypes = df.loc[df['itype'].isin(['B','NB','CLUB',])]
print_stuff = print_itypes[pd.to_numeric(print_itypes['replacement_cost'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
print_stuff.groupby("itype").agg({"replacement_cost": np.sum})
```

Output:

```
B   30.0018.0023.0019.0018.0020.0020.0013.0028.002...
CLUB    5.0015.0015.0010.0010.0015.0017.0015.0010.008....
NB  17.9529.0029.0016.0016.0016.9515.0015.0015.002...
```

Doesn't sum, just lists. I have to use `to_numeric` somewhere in the equation because otherwise, python chokes and complains about non_numeric ...etc. I can't get anything to work without this.

Comment: `print_stuff['replacement_cost']=print_stuff['replacement_cost'].astype(float)` and then execute the code..??

Comment: @anky_91That worked! If you want to set that up as an answer, I'll green check it. Thank you!!

Comment: @anky_91 Green checked! Thanks again, that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the column `replacement_cost` is a string, hence `sum()` concatenates the values instead of summing.

Try something like:

```
print_stuff['replacement_cost']=print_stuff['replacement_cost'].astype(float)
```

this will convert the column `replacement_cost` as a float and post that the `groupby().sum()` will work as intended.